# XSD Validation Errors localization

Tags: asp.net, xsd

I have a quick question:

Is there a "language pack" for XSD validation errors? I have my application's culture set to Spanish but when I validate a XML file against XSD I get the messages in English...

Thanks!

Comment: It would depend upon the validator you are using.